# passing variable with space + wildcard to remote ssh

Tags: unix, ssh, wildcard

Im trying to pass a variable with spaces in it to ssh.

```
report_name="This is a sample report"
dir=/home/sample

ssh $remote_host "ls -t "$dir/$report_name"*.xlsx | head -1"
```

output:

```
ls: is: No such file or directory
ls: a: No such file or directory
ls: sample: No such file or directory
ls: report*.xlsx: No such file or directory
```

how to make this work?

Edit:

**ANSWER:** 
After several trial and error I got it to work using below.

```
ssh $remote_host "ls -t "$dir"/'"$report_name"'.xlsx | head -1"
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the wildcard. Do you have reports like `This is a sample xyz.xlsx` where `xyz` is variable?

Comment: Yes, the actual reports have date and time stamp at the end. Something like "This is a sample report-20180411123430.xlsx"

Comment: is there alternative way without escaping the space with \ ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that does not involve escaping the white space:

```
#!/bin/bash
report_name="This is a sample report"
dir=/tmp

echo "First file:"
ssh $remote_host "ls -t '$dir/$report_name'*.xlsx | head -1"
echo "All files:"
ssh $remote_host "ls -t '$dir/$report_name'*.xlsx"
```

The outer double quotes essentially escape the inner single quotes. This results in them making it to the remote shell. Here's my output:

```
First file:
/tmp/This is a sample report_4.xlsx
All files:
/tmp/This is a sample report_4.xlsx
/tmp/This is a sample report_2.xlsx
/tmp/This is a sample report_3.xlsx
/tmp/This is a sample report_1.xlsx
```